# Arduino Serial Comparison

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I am writing a program that will send data via serial connection to an Arduino, the program sends either a 1 or a 2. When it sends it to the Arduino it can send it as a DEC by changing the "incoming byte" variable data type to int. Or what I think will be easier, is setting the data type to char which automatically converts it to the single number I need. That I have down and got that working easily but in the if statements I just can't get it to work no matter what I send I could send a 9 to the arduino but in the if statement it always treats it as if it was true and it runs both if statements as true and ends up printing the last 'lcd.print("LED 2");' statement. How would I write the if statement to do a correct comparison? It's giving me trouble putting the code in cleanly (in the triple apostrophe's) so here's a pastebin link to the code '''https://pastebin.com/JALyTu21'''. Sorry for bag grammar, new to English.

Comment: Also if you were wondering what the code is that sends that data to the Arduino here it is: https://pastebin.com/Veh39ZZC

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, in the secondary script I sent which is what sends the data to the Arduino it was constantly sending data I made it so it only sends data once and it worked!